# nginx server_name not opening specified location

Tags: nginx

I'm using **Nginx** as a proxy server to host multiple domains do different projects.

I have two configuration files inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available/

`config1.conf`

```
server {
  server_name                   app.domain1.com app.domain2.com;
  access_log                    /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.access.log;
  error_log                     /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.error.log;

  location / {
    root                      /var/www/html/qcg-app1/webapp/dist/webapp/;
    index                     index.html;
    try_files                 $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_redirect            off;
    proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
  }
}
```

and `config2.conf`

```
server {
    listen                       80;
    server_name                  app.domain3.io;
    access_log                   /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.access.log;
    error_log                    /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.error.log;


    location /docs {
      alias                       /var/www/html/qcg-app2/documentation/;
      try_files                   $uri$args $uri$args/ /docs/index.html;
    }

    location / {
        root                      /var/www/html/qcg-app2/dist/qcg-frontend/;
        index                     index.html;
        try_files                 $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        proxy_redirect            off;
        proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
    }
}
```

DNS is configured through Cloudflare to use SSL.

But when I visit, `app.domain1.com` or `app.domain2.com` both open the content of `app.domain3.com`, whereas both the domains should return content from their respective directory.

> sudo nginx -T

```
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "app.domain3.io" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
...
...

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/conf2.conf:
server {
    listen                       80;
    server_name                  app.domain3.io;
    access_log                   /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.access.log;
    error_log                    /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.error.log;


    location /docs {
      alias                       /var/www/html/qcg-frontend/documentation/;
      try_files                   $uri$args $uri$args/ /docs/index.html;
    }

    location / {
        root                      /var/www/html/qcg-app2/dist/qcg-frontend/;
        index                     index.html;
        try_files                 $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        proxy_redirect            off;
        proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ...
}

server {
  if ($host = app.domain3.io) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  listen                       80;
  server_name                  app.domain3.io;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/conf1.conf:
upstream scanning_api_server_new {
  server localhost:3000;
}


server {
  server_name                  api.domain1.com;
  access_log                   /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.access.log;
  error_log                    /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass                  http://scanning_api_server_new/;
      proxy_redirect              off;
    proxy_set_header            Host                  $host;
    proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP             $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-For       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header            X-Forwarded-Protocol  $scheme;
  }
}


server {
  server_name                   app.domain1.com app.domain2.com;
  access_log                    /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.access.log;
  error_log                     /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.error.log;

  location / {
    root                      /var/www/html/qcg-app1/webapp/dist/webapp/;
    index                     index.html;
    try_files                 $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    proxy_redirect            off;
    proxy_set_header          Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header          X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header          X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration that Nginx is using. Check if your `server` blocks with the correct `server_name` are present.

Comment: I have included the output of the command `sudo nginx -T`

Comment: Are you using `http` or `https`? If your server is being contacted using `https`, then there is only one `server` that can accept the request.

Comment: I'm using SSL certificate by Certbot on `domain3` only. `domain1` and `domain2` also works on HTTPS but by Cloudflare. Even if the `https` requests will be accepted by `domain3` setup then why does `domain1` and `domain2` points to that server even if they are not in the `server_name` of that config.